# How to make entire row clickable in UI-Grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using UI-GRID in my application to display the data. But then I came into a requirement where each row in UI-GRID must be clickable so that I can update the data in it or redirecting it to some other parsel. 
How can I achieve this? Is there a way in Angualr js for events on click?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-click` for this

```
<tr ng-click="yourScopeFunction(someValue)">
</tr>
```

Then in your controller

```
$scope.yourScopeFunction = function(someValue) {
    // do stuff.
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm actually using ui-grid and It's bounded. So how should I use in this way?

Comment: aha, check my second answer, does that help you?

Answer (score 0):

Using ui-grid you probably want to set `enableRowSelection` in the [gridOptions](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.selection.api:GridOptions) like this

```
 $scope.gridOptions = { 
     enableRowSelection: true,
     // ..
 };
```